# Why I'm getting this incompatibilities issues migrating from .net core rc1 to rc2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I'm trying to make a intermediate step moving from rc1 to rc2 before doing the final migration to v1.0

Right now I'm getting a bunch of incompatibility issues like these

> The dependency System.Diagnostics.Process 4.1.0-rc2-24027 does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.
>   Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error NU1002  The dependency System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0-rc2-24027 does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.

I'm trying to target .NET Framework 4.5.2 and .net Core

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4682#issuecomment-221176602) help? Seems to be a similar issue

Comment: Post your project.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The package `System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.Process/4.1.0-rc2-24027) only supports .Net Standard 1.3, [which corresponds to .Net Framework 4.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#net-platforms-support). So, to use that package, you can't target .Net 4.5.2, but have to target .Net 4.6 or higher.

The same applies to [`System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher/4.0.0-rc2-24027).

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this as soon as possible. I tested Yesterday targeting 4.6.2 and everything blew up. I'll try again taking into account that this is the solution so I have to make it work